# Can we move the document dynamically across shards in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb

I am building a tracking platform which has the following use cases.

1. Need to track 50,000 vehicles
2. Each vehicle relays its location every 60 secs.
3. Get API which returns all the vehicles in the X km range.

So, i need to scale writes and also achieve query isolation. 
I can create a shard cluster with geographical region as shard key(geohash). This will help me to balance the writes and also achieve query isolation. But what happens when a vehicle moves across regions does mangodb automatically move the document to the new shard in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the shard key fields for a record once written. Using the region as the shard key would prevent you from moving across regions unless you delete the record in the original region and the insert using the new one.

On choosing a shard key, look for one which matches your most common query pattern. Querying on the shard key will allow you to retrieve a record directly from a shard. Queries which don't use the shard key will have to perform a scatter gather query against all shards.

If are on or can use Mongodb 2.4, and you don't need to perform range based queries, you may want to consider using a [hashed shard key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4/#new-hashed-index-and-sharding-with-a-hashed-shard-key) which will allow for even distribution, even if your shard key is an monotonically increasing. See [this page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/select-shard-key/) for advice on choosing a shard key.